# WordNet word frequence use

Tags: nlp, wordnet, word-frequency

Is it possible in wordnet or any other way to know which sense of a word is used most. For e.g. the word "goods" is may be used more for kindness rather that for "products". Or the word "key" is used more for refering to a real key rather than "solution". e.g. The key to this problem is ...

is there anything like this??

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with word frequency. Surface word frequency would only tell you how many times a word occurs in a corpus.

However to find a sense frequency it is still an unsolved problem from an untagged corpus. (i.e. how many times a word in a certain context refers to a certain senses?). The best one can do now is to either:

1. Count the sense frequency from a sense-tagged corpus and then assumes that the sense frequency on the untagged corpus is similar or
2. Use a Word Sense Disambiguation software to tag an untagged corpus and then count the sense frequency from the tagged product. However, this is a convoluted method as most WSD software only does as well as using the Most Frequent Sense (MFS) from an already tagged corpus.